# There are link errors until I run "make clean; make" to clean build, why?

Tags: c++, linker, makefile

In C++, file A.cpp A.h, B.cpp, B.h.

File A.h include B.h. I write makefile for it and link errors occurs until I run "make clean; make" to clean build.

Link errors complain "undefined reference to Test::Test ...."( class Test is defined in B.h/cpp).

Comment: This is hard to fix without seeing your makefile.

Comment: Additionally, we don't know your class declarations/definitions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typical causes for linker errors, but without seeing your code or your Makefile we can't say for sure what's going on:

1. You didn't add B.cpp to your Makefile properly, or
2. "Test::Test ...." is not implemented, or
3. It's implemented, but you forgot to specify Test:: when implementing the function, so it doesn't belong to the class.